# How do I avoid namespace and class name collision in "vertically partitioned" assemblies?

Tags: .net, assemblies, namespaces, naming

By "Vertically partitioned", I mean having namespaces named after modules rather than "layers"

So,

- MyApp.Core
- MyApp.Accounting
- MyApp.OrderManagement
- MyApp.HR

instead of,

- MyApp.UI
- MyApp.Business
- MyApp.Data

The only issue I am running into is that sometimes those assemblies might have a part of the namespace that is same as a type name.

Let's say I create an Account related module and I name it MyApp.Account.dll with the base namespace being MyApp.Account.  Inevitably, I need to create a class named Account.  Then I have to use namespace or type aliases.

Other than being very creative with names, has anyone else experience cutting assemblies this way and dealt with name collision issues?

Comment: May I ask what is the need for you to create your name space like this ? Why not MyApp.Business.Account ?

Comment: Are you saying that the namespace would be MyApp.Business, which would contain the type Account?  If so, that's one way of handling it - in fact, I'm thinking about keeping the assemblies names as MyApp.Accounting, then namespace as MyApp.DomainObjects, under which Account type would be created.

Comment: The reason I am creating these vertical slices is so that each "module" can be developed and maintained separately.  Instead of having all of your features in a single assembly under "Business", you'd have many assemblies containing whatever "layers" are required to support a single feature.

Answer (score 9):

In the past, I've dealt with this two ways:

1) Pluralizing the namespaces or making them gerunds where appropriate (adding an -ing suffix). For example, `MyApp.Orders` can safely contain an `Order` class. (Similarly, stick with "MyApp.Accounting" rather than "MyApp.Account").

2) By appending `Domain` to the namespace (a bit unsatisfying, but effective).